# Typescript file auto create Javascript in vs2017 without tsconfig.json globally project level

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am working on typescript project.we have to generate the javascript file automatically by saving the ts file without any tsconfig.json.

exmaple **test.ts** file here

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person: Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

let user = { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "User" };

document.body.textContent = greeter(user);
```

we can use tsconfig.json to generate the javascript file, it is working fine. it is creating the javascript files for associated .ts file.

but without using any .json setup, can  we generate the .js file automatically by saving .ts file in vs2017.

what are all the settings we have to configure to make it done in vs2017.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a tsconfig.json file, then the project property pages should would be the place to set CompileOnSave.

[image]